# adding a specific number of divs jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to add a specific number of divs with a class of box to the body everytime the page loads here is my code

```
  var divAmount = 4;
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("<div class='box'></div>").appendTo("body");
$('.box').each(function(index){
    if(index < divAmount){
        $("<div class='box'></div>").appendTo("body");
    }
}); 
 });
```

This is only adding the first appendTo div how would i go about adding the number that i want?

Comment: You know what a `for` loop is.

Comment: i tried looking into it but the results on google take you to the each function

Comment: You should really learn at least the basics of javascript before jumping into jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it as:

```
var divAmount = 4;
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < divAmount; i++) {
    $("<div class='box' />").appendTo("body");
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this after they told me to use the for loop howver it only adds one div

Comment: I'm sorry its been working just adding it in the same location so look like 1 my bad